# show ruby date as a RFC 3339 timestamp

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know how I can convert a ruby time class instance into a RFC 3339 timestamp?

The output should be something like this:

> "2013-10-13T13:34:52.000+02:00"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require 'date'
Time.now.to_datetime.rfc3339
```

Comment: So far, this is the only answer I've seen that actually includes the `require` line.